# Getter and setter methods for wrapper class in salesforce

Tags: apex, visualforce, getter, setter

Please help me in clearing this doubt..

I have a wrapper class which I am using to store JSON values received from external system,  on doing Json.deserialize it parses all the values as received.

```
Wrapper class:`
global class wrappercontainer{
    @AuraEnabled
    global List<Purposes>result{get;set;}
    global class Purposes{
        @AuraEnabled
        public String fromSourceSystem{get;set;}
      @AuraEnabled
            public string methodJob{
get{
if(some condition){
                    system.debug('inside getter');
                    return 'XYZ';
                }
}
set;}
```

From the lightning page I set the value of methodJob to 'ABC'. While I put a debug after Json.desearilze , I get the value as ABC which is set from the lightning page.

but if I do wrappercontainer.methodJob in the apex code my getter methods invoke and it makes the value as XYZ because of the condition being set.

Is this is expected that getter methods will be called in apex controller as well when referencing the associated wrapper variables.

```
reqcontainer = (wrappercontainer)JSON.deserializeStrict(container,wrappercontainer.class);
            system.debug('ContainerFromSFParse:-'+wrappercontainer.result);
```

DEBUG: I get the value which is set from page i.e.ABC

On doing jst after after the debug

```
for (wrappercontainer.result obj: reqcontainer.result){
                    system.debug('Containeragain:-'+obj.methodJob);
```

here the getter method invoke and makes the value as XYZ

Comment: Can you post your code from component/JS as how you are setting the values from the component layer?

Comment: You should include the full condition & getter for your wrapper class -  a test wrapper run in the dev console with a `get` returning a fixed value always return that value in my test, even when trying to overwrite the value or serialize the object.

Comment: @battery.cord- Hi so mean my getter will be called when I access wrapperclass.variable ? little strange as in why my getter method doesn't get called in JSON.deserialization, that time also it assigns the value to the variable. I only see getter method called when I tried with wrapper.variable

Comment: @JayantDas: I am not setting any thing on component layer. its on apex class only , but my question was why getter method was called why access the wrapper variable but not while deserialization of the same wrapper class